# Change Background of Buttons after Clicks in Angular 8?

Tags: html, css, button, angular8, background-color

I have 4 buttons in a row in HTML of my Angular 8 Component.I am using ant design (antd) library.

**What I Want ?**

- I want to change the background-color of button when it is
  clicked.
- Previously pressed button should return to original styling when
  other button is pressed. And newly pressed should be highlighted
  by changing background-color

**Contraint**

I want to achieve this without `click-event` method.I want to do this purely CSS(styling) based like giving buttons `id` and `class` and then implementing it ?

I checked few stack-overflow posts relevant to this problem but those did't helped. Few using `hover` and `active` classes

**HTML**

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
      <button (click)="redirectToHub1()" type="button" class="ant-btn ant-btn-primary ant-btn-lg"
        ant-click-animating-without-extra-node="false" ><span>Hub 1</span></button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
      <button (click)="redirectToHub2()" type="button" class="ant-btn ant-btn-primary ant-btn-lg"
        ant-click-animating-without-extra-node="false" >Hub2</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
      <button (click)="redirectToHub3()" type="button" class="ant-btn ant-btn-primary ant-btn-lg"
        ant-click-animating-without-extra-node="false" >Hub 3</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
      <button (click)="redirectToHub4()" type="button" class="ant-btn ant-btn-primary ant-btn-lg"
        ant-click-animating-without-extra-node="false" >Hub 4</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Typescript**

```
 redirectToHub1() {
    this.router.navigate(["/hubs/hub1"], {
      queryParams: { id: `${this.hubCode}` },
    });
  }
 redirectToHub2() {
    this.router.navigate(["/hubs/hub2"], {
      queryParams: { id: `${this.hubCode}` },
    });
  }
redirectToHub3() {
    this.router.navigate(["/hubs/hub3"], {
      queryParams: { id: `${this.hubCode}` },
    });
  }
 redirectToHub2() {
    this.router.navigate(["/hubs/hub4"], {
      queryParams: { id: `${this.hubCode}` },
    });
  }
```

**Current Display**

[image: Hubs Button]

**Required Display**

[image: Required View]

It works fine with below styling but when I add `(click)="redirectToHub()"` methods it does't work

```
.ant-btn:active, .redirect_btn:focus{
  background: blue;
}
```

Comment: You should learn about pseudo classes `:active, :focus, :visited`

Comment: `#hub_steps_btns :hover
{
background-color:red;
color: red;
}` I tried something like this but it is not working

Comment: Check added answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62652013/change-background-of-buttons-after-clicks-in-angular-8/62653202#62653202

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please fins the sample, this will be helpful.

```css
.btn {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background: #e7e7e7;
  outline: none;
}

.btn:active, .btn:focus{
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Test 1</button>
<button class="btn">Test 2</button>
<button class="btn">Test 3</button>
<button class="btn">Test 4</button>
<button class="btn">Test 5</button>
```

Comment: It works fine if I remove `click` event . But when I add  `(click)="redirectToHub2()"` it does't works

Comment: What you are doing inside the function? , are showing Hub on screen basis on selected button? you need to maintain variable for selected item. `[ngClass]="{'my-class': thisButtonId === 'selectedButtonId'}"`

Comment: I have 4 `components` on each click it goes to relevant component. Basically the screen with 4 `buttons` is a different component I have appended it in each `hub`  using `app-selector`